# How to use numeric values for citation links instead of footnotes in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, bibliography

I am creating a documentation with [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) where I am citing papers with standard numeric way of citation e.g.

**file1.rst**

> bone, extracellular matrix[2], fluids, and diffusing chemicals[3]

**references.rst**

> .. [2]    Merks, R. M. H., Newman `<MoreText>`
>
> .. [3]     Turing, A. M. `<MoreText>`

But it does not work. I see that numeric references are only for footnotes and for citations you have to use alphanumeric text as mentioned in [documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#footnotes).

I believe that many people cite using numbered references. Is there any way this to achieve this?

Comment: Not out of the box. I think there is a related item in the project's issue tracker. https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4131

Answer (score 6):

It is possible using [sphinxcontrib-bibtex](https://github.com/mcmtroffaes/sphinxcontrib-bibtex) by Matthias C. M. Troffaes that relies on [BibTex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX) files for storing the citations.

Install it (see link above) and add

```
extensions = ['sphinxcontrib.bibtex']
```

To the `conf.py` file of your project.

Add a page with the bibliography

```
.. bibliography:: /path/to/bibtex/file.bib
   :style: plain
```

The style "plain" is the typical numerical citation style. Note that as for latex usage, you do not put the number in yourself. A citation is done as

> Sphinx is great for documentation :cite:`sphinx_doc_web`

and the extension will place the number appropriately.